# how to upload mustache template with easy way?

Tags: jquery, html, mustache

i started to learn mustache.js but i tried to load external template (template.html). Below codes are working fine. but i dont like "$.get('template.html', . . .. " method. is there any shorter and cheaper way. for example :   **<link href="path/to/template.mustache" rel="template" id="templateName"/  >**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <h2>Titles</h2>
    <ul id="talktitles">
    </ul>
    <script src="mustache.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.getJSON('/data/speakers.json', function(data) {
                //var template = $('#speakers-template').html();

               // console.log(template);
               // var info = Mustache.render(template, data);
               // $('#talktitles').html(info);

  $.get('template.html', function(template, textStatus, jqXhr) {
            var info =Mustache.render($(template).filter('#speakers-template').html(), data);
            $('#talktitles').html(info);
        });

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="talktitles"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use a build tool like Grunt to build a JavaScript global object containing all of your compiled templates - https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-mustache

Comment: You could write a script that reads such `link` elements. Considering you seem to have multiple templates in one file, it would make sense to restructure your code anyway, and load the file and split it up into separate templates beforehand. One further idea could be to have your template file be a JSON file, which would simplify the loading of the templates significantly, because the multiple slow HTML parsing would be unnecessary. However this would make editing the template file more difficult.